# Get Leaflet marker options by Leaflet ContextMenu

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, leaflet, marker

I try to use ContextMenu to run DeleteMaker function, but ContextMenu just get marker current Latlng, not like other leaflet events like "click", "dblclick" ... what can get marker options info.

Example :

```
var marker = new customMarker([28.63278, 77.21972],{
    clickable: true,
    name: 'Connaught Place',
    type: 'Neighbourhood'
    }).on('click', onClick).addTo(map);

function onClick(e) {
$('#content').html("
    Name: "+this.options.name+"
    Type: "+this.options.type+"
">;")
}
```

that code above can get Options value with event "click", HOW CAN I GET options value LIKE THIS WITH CONTEXTMENU

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get marker options from outer, simply use variable name to get there.

```
marker.options.name
marker.options.type
```

[See example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8865/). Is this what you asked?

Comment: Tks, but I add a list of marker to layer by loop, how I get it when use contextMenu event //it's work on 'click', 'dblclick'...

Comment: You are storing markers in some array or just adding them into the map? Please provide some code on JSFiddle or other testing enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the context menu plugin for leaflet (https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu) and I noticed the same situation. What I did was to use the "contextmenu" option for the marker event to create a global variable with the marker.options.id when a right click is detected. Then, using the context menu callback function, use that global variable (that has the marker id), fetch the marker associated to that id and THEN remove the marker from the markers array. Yes, I use a markers array because is easier to work when you have thousand of markers in the map.

It's not elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the contextmenu pluging, it's pretty straight forward.
You could use a global variable like Alberto said. Or just feed the callback property of the contextmenu item with a function call.

```
var type = "type";
var name = "name";     
var marker = new customMarker(28.63278, 77.21972,
                {
                    name: name,
                    type: type,
                    contextmenu: true,
                    contextmenuWidth: 140,
                    contextmenuItems: [ { text: 'Show name/type', callback: function () { SetContent(name, type) } }]
                });

function SetContent(name, type)
{
      $('#content').html("Name: " + name + "Type: " + type);
}
```